# Pug file sent with Express never loads

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am making a website using express to send pug files, and it is all working except for one endpoint. I have no idea why, but then it might just be me missing something plainly obvious. There are no errors.

My dashboard-routes.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const guilds = require('../../data/guilds');
const { validateGuild } = require('../modules/middleware');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/servers/:id', validateGuild,
  async (req, res) => res.render('dashboard/show', {
    savedGuild: await guilds.get(req.params.id),
    subtitle: `- Dashboard`
}));
```

validateGuild function in middleware.js:

```
module.exports.validateGuild = async (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.guild = res.locals.guilds.find(g => g.id === req.params.id);
  return (res.locals.guild)
    ? next()
    : res.render('errors/404');
};
```

I am possibly missing some obvious mistake, but I have not found any solution. All help appreciated.

Edit: `guilds.get(req.params.id)` returns nothing, and I still do not know why.
This is guilds.js:

```
const SavedGuild = require('./models/guild');

module.exports = new class {
  async get(id) {
    return await SavedGuild.findById(id)
      || await new SavedGuild({ _id: id }).save();
  }
}
```

and this is models/guild.js:

```
const { model } = require('mongoose');

class GeneralModule {
  prefix = '.';
  blacklistedChannelIds = [];
}

module.exports = model('guild', {
  _id: String,
  general: { type: Object, default: new GeneralModule() }
});
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting this route with?  Have you verified with `console.log()` statements whether your route handler and middleware are getting called?  What you have not described here are any of the basic debugging steps you've taken to troubleshoot this and what you learned when doing that.

Comment: Why is `validateGuild()` marked as `async`?

Comment: @jfriend00 After a few minutes the server just returns a 502, and the validateGuild function is working properly (I have console logged).

Comment: Should the function not be marked as async?

Comment: You generally only mark a function `async` if you want it to return a promise and you want to use `await` inside the function.  In `validateGuild()`, you aren't using `await` and Express does not pay any attention to the return value from middleware so I don't see any reason for it to be `async`.  It's probably not causing a problem, just not a correct design.

Comment: Are you sure that `await guilds.get(req.params.id)` is succeeding?  You don't have any error handling if it rejects.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated the code to ```router.get('/servers/:id', validateGuild, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(`test:` + await guilds.get(req.params.id))

  res.render('dashboard/show', {
    savedGuild: await guilds.get(req.params.id),
    subtitle: `- Dashboard`
  })
})
```
and nothing is logged

this is guild.js:
```
const SavedGuild = require('./models/guild');

module.exports = new class {
  async get(id) {
    return await SavedGuild.findById(id)
      || await new SavedGuild({ _id: id }).save();
  }
}
```
and i still dont know whats wrong

Comment: Then, either `validateGuild()` is causing an error or your route definition is not matching.  You can instrument `validateGuild()` to learn more and see if it's getting called.  This is basic troubleshooting steps.